# OpenGL glGetUniformBlockIndex returns INVALID_INDEX on nvidea gpus's

Tags: c++, opengl, gpu, rendering

I've been working on this opengl game engine for quite a while now, and I'm making a game in it as well with procedurally generated planets. However, I got some weird problems that I've been stuck on for 3 weeks now.

To generate the planets on the fly, I make use of a material consisting of a tesselation and geometry shader to do the generating in. This way, it's super fast. Now in the tessellation evaluation shader, I use a uniform buffer block to send the parameters for the planet generation to the gpu (which is I believe 48 bytes x number of noise layers).

Now all this works fine on my desktop PC which has a radeon r9 390, and also on my laptop which has a gtx 1060. However, on the following desktop gpu's i get an INVALID_INDEX when calling glGetUniformBlockIndex and obviously it doesn't work as it is trying to generate with incorrect parameters.
- gtx 1050
- gtx 1060
- gtx 960
- gtx 970
- rtx 2080

On the following gpu's everything is working fine with no errors:
- radeon r9 390
- rx 580
- hd 7770

I don't have any other gpus available to me to test any further.

Now after doing some research I know that there is a limit on how big your uniform buffer block can be, as well as how many and how many components you can have etc. However, considering I brought the max number of layers down to 1 and tested again, the problem still persisted. It also can't be a memory shortage issue because an hd 7770 has only 1 GB of vram, while a 1060 has between 4-6 GB of vram and it still happens on a 1060.

Another thing I found is that shader variables can be optimized out by the driver when the variable does not contribute to the output, and as you will be able to see from the shader code it deffinitely does contribute to the output.

So, onto some code

In the material class there is a CreateUniformBuffer function that gets the index of the uniform buffer block and binds it to a buffer allowing to edit it. Note that the program already crashes after getting INVALID_INDEX so getting the index must be where the issue lies.

```
GLuint Material::CreateUniformBuffer(const std::string& name, GLuint bufferSize)
{
    GLuint uniformBlockIndex = glGetUniformBlockIndex(m_pShader->m_ShaderProgramID, name.data());
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());
    if (uniformBlockIndex == GL_INVALID_INDEX)
    {
        Utilities::Debug::LogError("Material::CreateUniformBuffer > Uniform buffer block with name " + name + " not found!");
        return 0;
    }

    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());
    glUniformBlockBinding(m_pShader->m_ShaderProgramID, uniformBlockIndex, m_BufferBindIndex);
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());

    // Uniform buffer object for lights
    GLuint bufferID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &bufferID);
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, bufferID);
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());
    glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, bufferSize, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());
    glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, uniformBlockIndex, bufferID);
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());

    m_UniformBufferObjects.push_back(bufferID);

    ++m_BufferBindIndex;
    return bufferID;
}
```

This is the tessellation evaluation shader, note that there is an #include "SimplexNoise" line at the top, which does not work in opengl, however, the engine has a precompiler stage for shaders where it reads through the shader code and replaces any #include directives with the contents of the file that its including before compiling the shader.

planet_te.shader

```
#version 450

#include "SimplexNoise.shader"

layout(triangles, equal_spacing, cw) in;
in vec3 tcPosition[];
out vec3 tePosition;
out float teElevation;

uniform int NumNoiseLayers;

struct NoiseLayer
{
    float Strength;
    float BaseRoughness;
    float Roughness;
    float Persistance;

    vec3 Center;
    float MinValue;

    int NumLayers;
    int UseFirstLayerAsMask;
    int NoiseFilterType;
    float Weight;
};

const int MaxNoiseLayers = 4;
layout(std140) uniform NoiseBlock
{
    NoiseLayer NoiseLayers[MaxNoiseLayers];
} _NoiseData;

float Evaluate(vec3 p, int layer)
{
    int filterType = _NoiseData.NoiseLayers[layer].NoiseFilterType;
    if (filterType == 0)
        return SimpleEvaluate(p, int(_NoiseData.NoiseLayers[layer].NumLayers), _NoiseData.NoiseLayers[layer].BaseRoughness, _NoiseData.NoiseLayers[layer].Roughness, _NoiseData.NoiseLayers[layer].Persistance, _NoiseData.NoiseLayers[layer].Center, _NoiseData.NoiseLayers[layer].MinValue, _NoiseData.NoiseLayers[layer].Strength);

    return RigidEvaluate(p, int(_NoiseData.NoiseLayers[layer].NumLayers), _NoiseData.NoiseLayers[layer].BaseRoughness, _NoiseData.NoiseLayers[layer].Roughness, _NoiseData.NoiseLayers[layer].Persistance, _NoiseData.NoiseLayers[layer].Center, _NoiseData.NoiseLayers[layer].MinValue, _NoiseData.NoiseLayers[layer].Strength, _NoiseData.NoiseLayers[layer].Weight);
}

float CalculateTotalStrength()
{
    float strength = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NumNoiseLayers; i++)
    {
        strength += _NoiseData.NoiseLayers[i].Strength;
    }
    return strength;
}

float LayeredEvaluate(vec3 p)
{
    float firstLayerValue = 0.0;
    float elevationAverage = 0.0;

    float totalStrength = CalculateTotalStrength();

    float unscaledElevation = 0.0;
    float scaledElevation = 0.0;

    float noiseValue = 0.0;
    float strengthPercentage = 0.0;
    if (NumNoiseLayers > 0)
    {
        unscaledElevation = Evaluate(p, 0);
        scaledElevation = max(0.0, unscaledElevation);
        noiseValue = scaledElevation;
        elevationAverage = unscaledElevation;
        firstLayerValue = noiseValue;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < NumNoiseLayers; i++)
    {
        float mask = (_NoiseData.NoiseLayers[i].UseFirstLayerAsMask == 1) ? firstLayerValue : 1.0;
        unscaledElevation = Evaluate(p, 0);
        scaledElevation = max(0.0, unscaledElevation);
        elevationAverage += unscaledElevation;

        noiseValue += scaledElevation;
    }

    elevationAverage /= totalStrength;

    teElevation = clamp(elevationAverage * 115.0, -0.99, 0.99);

    return noiseValue;
}

void main()
{
    vec3 p0 = gl_TessCoord.x * tcPosition[0];
    vec3 p1 = gl_TessCoord.y * tcPosition[1];
    vec3 p2 = gl_TessCoord.z * tcPosition[2];
    tePosition = normalize(p0 + p1 + p2);
    float hieght = LayeredEvaluate(tePosition);
    gl_Position = vec4(tePosition * (1.0 + hieght), 1);
}
```

SimplexNoise.shader

```
const int RandomSize = 256;
const float Sqrt3 = 1.7320508075688772935;
const float Sqrt5 = 2.2360679774997896964;
uniform int _random[512];

/// Skewing and unskewing factors for 2D, 3D and 4D, 
/// some of them pre-multiplied.
const float F2 = 0.5 * (Sqrt3 - 1.0);
const float G2 = (3.0 - Sqrt3) / 6.0;
const float G22 = G2 * 2.0 - 1;
const float F3 = 1.0 / 3.0;
const float G3 = 1.0 / 6.0;
const float F4 = (Sqrt5 - 1.0) / 4.0;
const float G4 = (5.0 - Sqrt5) / 20.0;
const float G42 = G4 * 2.0;
const float G43 = G4 * 3.0;
const float G44 = G4 * 4.0 - 1.0;

const int[] Grad3 =
{
    1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0,
    -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1,
    1, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1,
    0, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1
};

float Dot(int index, float x, float y, float z)
{
    return Grad3[index] * x + Grad3[index + 1] * y + Grad3[index + 2] * z;
}

float Dot(int index, float x, float y)
{
    return Grad3[index] * x + Grad3[index + 1] * y;
}

int FastFloor(float x)
{
    return int(x) >= 0 ? int(x) : int(x) - 1;
}

float Evaluate(vec3 p)
{
    float x = p.x;
    float y = p.y;
    float z = p.z;
    float n0 = 0.0, n1 = 0.0, n2 = 0.0, n3 = 0.0;

    // Noise contributions from the four corners
    // Skew the input space to determine which simplex cell we're in
    float s = (x + y + z) * F3;

    // for 3D
    int i = FastFloor(x + s);
    int j = FastFloor(y + s);
    int k = FastFloor(z + s);

    float t = (i + j + k) * G3;

    // The x,y,z distances from the cell origin
    float x0 = x - (i - t);
    float y0 = y - (j - t);
    float z0 = z - (k - t);

    // For the 3D case, the simplex shape is a slightly irregular tetrahedron.
    // Determine which simplex we are in.
    // Offsets for second corner of simplex in (i,j,k)
    int i1, j1, k1;

    // coords
    int i2, j2, k2; // Offsets for third corner of simplex in (i,j,k) coords

    if (x0 >= y0)
    {
        if (y0 >= z0)
        {
            // X Y Z order
            i1 = 1;
            j1 = 0;
            k1 = 0;
            i2 = 1;
            j2 = 1;
            k2 = 0;
        }
        else if (x0 >= z0)
        {
            // X Z Y order
            i1 = 1;
            j1 = 0;
            k1 = 0;
            i2 = 1;
            j2 = 0;
            k2 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // Z X Y order
            i1 = 0;
            j1 = 0;
            k1 = 1;
            i2 = 1;
            j2 = 0;
            k2 = 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // x0 < y0
        if (y0 < z0)
        {
            // Z Y X order
            i1 = 0;
            j1 = 0;
            k1 = 1;
            i2 = 0;
            j2 = 1;
            k2 = 1;
        }
        else if (x0 < z0)
        {
            // Y Z X order
            i1 = 0;
            j1 = 1;
            k1 = 0;
            i2 = 0;
            j2 = 1;
            k2 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // Y X Z order
            i1 = 0;
            j1 = 1;
            k1 = 0;
            i2 = 1;
            j2 = 1;
            k2 = 0;
        }
    }

    // A step of (1,0,0) in (i,j,k) means a step of (1-c,-c,-c) in (x,y,z),
    // a step of (0,1,0) in (i,j,k) means a step of (-c,1-c,-c) in (x,y,z),
    // and
    // a step of (0,0,1) in (i,j,k) means a step of (-c,-c,1-c) in (x,y,z),
    // where c = 1/6.

    // Offsets for second corner in (x,y,z) coords
    float x1 = x0 - i1 + G3;
    float y1 = y0 - j1 + G3;
    float z1 = z0 - k1 + G3;

    // Offsets for third corner in (x,y,z)
    float x2 = x0 - i2 + F3;
    float y2 = y0 - j2 + F3;
    float z2 = z0 - k2 + F3;

    // Offsets for last corner in (x,y,z)
    float x3 = x0 - 0.5;
    float y3 = y0 - 0.5;
    float z3 = z0 - 0.5;

    // Work out the hashed gradient indices of the four simplex corners
    int ii = i & 0xff;
    int jj = j & 0xff;
    int kk = k & 0xff;

    // Calculate the contribution from the four corners
    float t0 = 0.6 - x0 * x0 - y0 * y0 - z0 * z0;

    if (t0 > 0)
    {
        t0 *= t0;
        int gi0 = _random[ii + _random[jj + _random[kk]]] % 12;
        n0 = t0 * t0 * Dot(gi0 * 3, x0, y0, z0);
    }

    float t1 = 0.6 - x1 * x1 - y1 * y1 - z1 * z1;
    if (t1 > 0)
    {
        t1 *= t1;
        int gi1 = _random[ii + i1 + _random[jj + j1 + _random[kk + k1]]] % 12;
        n1 = t1 * t1 * Dot(gi1 * 3, x1, y1, z1);
    }

    float t2 = 0.6 - x2 * x2 - y2 * y2 - z2 * z2;
    if (t2 > 0)
    {
        t2 *= t2;
        int gi2 = _random[ii + i2 + _random[jj + j2 + _random[kk + k2]]] % 12;
        n2 = t2 * t2 * Dot(gi2 * 3, x2, y2, z2);
    }

    float t3 = 0.6 - x3 * x3 - y3 * y3 - z3 * z3;
    if (t3 > 0)
    {
        t3 *= t3;
        int gi3 = _random[ii + 1 + _random[jj + 1 + _random[kk + 1]]] % 12;
        n3 = t3 * t3 * Dot(gi3 * 3, x3, y3, z3);
    }

    // Add contributions from each corner to get the final noise value.
    // The result is scaled to stay just inside [-1,1]
    return float(n0 + n1 + n2 + n3) * 32;
}

float Evaluate(vec3 p, float strength, float roughness, vec3 centre)
{
    float noise = (Evaluate(p * roughness + centre) + 1.0) * 0.5;
    return noise * strength;
}

float SimpleEvaluate(vec3 p, int numLayers, float baseRoughness, float roughness, float persistance, vec3 centre, float minValue, float strength)
{
    float noiseValue = 0.0;
    float frequency = baseRoughness;
    float amplitude = 1.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numLayers; i++)
    {
        float v = Evaluate(p * frequency + centre);
        noiseValue += (v + 1) * 0.5 * amplitude;
        frequency *= roughness;
        amplitude *= persistance;
    }

    //noiseValue = max(0.0, noiseValue - minValue);
    return (noiseValue - minValue) * strength;
}

float RigidEvaluate(vec3 p, int numLayers, float baseRoughness, float roughness, float persistance, vec3 centre, float minValue, float strength, float weight)
{
    float noiseValue = 0.0;
    float frequency = baseRoughness;
    float amplitude = 1.0;
    weight = 1.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numLayers; i++)
    {
        float v = 1.0 - abs(Evaluate(p * frequency + centre));
        v *= v;
        v *= weight;
        weight = v;
        noiseValue += v * amplitude;
        frequency *= roughness;
        amplitude *= persistance;
    }

    //noiseValue = max(0.0, noiseValue - minValue);
    return (noiseValue - minValue) * strength;
}
```

Note that this is a noise algorithm I found online and converted it to glsl code (shoutout to Sebastian Lague for his amazing series on procedural planets in Unity)

I am using SDL to open a window and to handle input, audio and textrendering, OpenGL 4.6 and GLEW 2.1.0

Things I've tried:
- Lower the size of the block by lowering the number of layers (so a smaller array)
- A uniform array instead of a uniform block (same outcome only the crash is not there, but for gpus that had the crash it just renders all planets incorrectly)
- Updating SDL and all its plugins to the latest version, and updating OpenGL to 4.6 from 3.1, also updating GLEW from 1.10.0 to 2.1.0
- Changing the name of the uniform block
- Playing around with amount of values inside the block (while respecting the size having to be a multiplication of 4 floats)
- Having binding = 0 next to the std140 in the glsl code
- Logging any errors or warnings from shader compilation to the console (no errors or warnings found)

I have a bit of a deadline next friday to upload a build to steam, and they won't except it if it only works on amd gpu's (understandable off course) so I'm hoping someone has an idea of what I'm doing wrong here, or has had a similar issue before in the past, any help is welcome!

EDIT: I tried using an SSBO, this had a harsh impact on performance, and while it does not crash anymore (because I'm not looking for the block index by name) it does not render anything on nvidea gpu's and spit out Unknown Errors in the log file.

Code for binding the SSBO

```
GLuint Material::CreateShaderStorageBuffer(const std::string& name, GLsizeiptr bufferSize, const void* data, GLint bindingIndex, GLenum usage)
{
    GLuint ssbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ssbo);
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo);
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());
    glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, bufferSize, data, usage);
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());
    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, bindingIndex, ssbo);
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());

    /*GLuint blockIndex = glGetProgramResourceIndex(m_pShader->m_ShaderProgramID, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, name.c_str());
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());

    if (blockIndex == GL_INVALID_INDEX)
    {
        Utilities::Debug::LogError("Material::CreateShaderStorageBuffer > Shader Storage Buffer Block with name " + name + " not found!");
        return 0;
    }

    glShaderStorageBlockBinding(m_pShader->m_ShaderProgramID, blockIndex, bindingIndex);
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());*/

    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, NULL);
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());
    return ssbo;
}
```

Code for setting SSBO data

```
void Material::WriteToShaderStorageBuffer(GLuint ssboID, const void* data, GLsizeiptr size)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssboID);
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());
    GLvoid* bufferData = glMapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());
    memcpy(bufferData, data, size);
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, NULL);
    Utilities::Debug::LogGLError(glGetError());
}
```

The change in the shader to turn the uniform block into an SSBO

```
const int MaxNoiseLayers = 4;
layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer NoiseBlock
{
    NoiseLayer NoiseLayers[MaxNoiseLayers];
} _NoiseData;
```

Comment: If it is an issue of the size of the uniform block, then use a [Shader Storage Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) instead.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I've implemented these just now but I've noticed quite a large impact on performace from this, after a bit of experimenting I figured that using GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW as the buffer usage yields best results, however I still seem to have anywhere between 50-100 fps less than with the uniform buffer, a small optimization to only write to the buffer when data changes helps a lot but I'm still noticing between 20-50 fps less than with the uniform buffer, I'm not sure if I can live witth that, also I don't think 4 x 48 bytes is too large for a uniform buffer?

Comment: SSBO's did not solve the problem, it got rid of the crash (probably because I'm not searching for the block index) but on all desktop nvidea gpu's it seems to not render a single planet anymore, while on my PC (with an amd gpu) it seems to render what was expected to render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the issue was caused by the int array buffer _random[512] in the SimplexNoise shader file, I'm not sure why this was causing issues on only nvidea gpu's but I am assuming it was some kind of limit it was exceeding on nvideas gpus that caused the entire shader to break without any warnings or errors.

I fixed it by turning this array into another UBO and bind it to index 1.